# Contraint layout confusion about parent in android

Tags: android, constraints, android-constraintlayout

Below are two textviews with different constraint the first textview is 'Home' and it contains `app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"` constraint and another is 'World' and contains the `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`. So both are gives the same result. I mean both textviews are placed on the right side of the screen.

below is the code.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="World"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_home"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

So what is the difference anyway with respect to parent.

Comment: If you haven't read the official document about ConstrainLayout yet , then please do refer the official document here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html so you can get the better idea about ConstraintLayout and all the Constraints.

Comment: Firstly don't use right to right of. instead of that use start to start of and end to end of also Assign these constraints to both textviews that's is start to start of and end to end of. you will get expected result.